# IE7 body width increases with floated element

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

In IE7 standards mode rendering, a strange thing happens with the following body:

```
<body>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <span style="float: right; font-style: italic;">some text to the right</span>
    other text to the left
  </div>
</body>
```

The body width doubles, even though the `<div>` width looks correct. There is just a huge amount of empty space appearing to the right, and a horizontal scrollbar.

Page rendering is correct if I either switch to IE8 standards mode rendering, or if I stay in IE7 mode but remove the `font-style` CSS rule:

```
<body>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <span style="float: right;">some text to the right</span>
    other text to the left
  </div>
</body>
```

What is going on here?

PS: Interestingly, the same happens if I use `<em>` or `<i>` instead of `font-style: italic`. With `<em>` — wide body, without — normal body. Changing font style seems to break it, while changing font weight (bold) does not have any negative effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's happening, but then again, IE works in mysterious ways ... Either way, this should fix it:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden;">
```

Comment: Declaring `overflow: hidden;` fixed it. Thanks. :)